# Minimizing cost for a given volume

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization

288 m3 tank will be made in the form of a rectangular prism. The cost of 1 m2 of  top and bottom walls is 40 euros. The cost of 1 m2 of side wall is 30 euros. What should be the edges to be cheap as possible? I just know wolume of rectangular prism but there are 3 different variables. How I can apply minimization by taking derivative?

Answer (score 1):

Let the height of the box be $z$, and let the other two dimensions be $x$ and $y$.

If this problem came up in first-year (one-variable) calculus,
where we knew nothing of Lagrange multipliers or even gradients,
we could assume (temporarily) that one of the variables was a constant,
so that the remaining variables are functions of each other.
For example, assume $z$ is constant, and write $y$ as a function of $x$.

Under this assumption,
the cost of the box can be written as function of $x$ alone
(using the constant $z$) and can be minimized.
That tells us the minimum-cost box for any given choice of constant $z$.
If we now treat $z$ as a variable, we can find the box that costs the
least among all boxes with any height $z$.

Comment: Many thanks for helps :) I got it. I found a=b by using Lagrange Multipliers. But I couldn't say something about c, to know that is a=b was enough. I wrote c as a function of a in the equation. Then I took a derivative and solved it. Answer is a=b=6 and c=8. Min cost is 8640 euros.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

If the length, breadth & the height be $a,b,c$

$abc=288$

Now using [Lagrange Multiplier](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeMultiplier.html),   $$f(a,b,c)=2ab\cdot40+2(bc+ca)30+\lambda(abc-288)$$